# nearly 2 years old son fears characters, dolls and someone knocking on door (bully niece)

Tags: development, fears, bullying

Whenever I take my kid to the mall, he fears going to the soft toys section and fears all the dolls, characters, stuffed animals.

Another thing I observed is that if we are in our room and somebody knocks the door, he runs crying to the far end of the room near the bed (I think that place is his comfort zone).

My niece is nearly 1 year older than my son and she is a big rough or type of bully. She doesn't care while hitting him and he is developing fear for her. He hits her whenever he gets opportunity (I observed he gets guts of hitting if I'm watching). When she hits back he cries and runs away or comes towards me.

How can I make him overcome these fears?

Comment: I feel that there are really 2 questions here: Your son's general and specific fearfulness AND the behavior of your niece. For the latter you might want to provide more detail, such as where are her parents, what do you do to prevent the kids from fighting, and so forth.

Comment: Please clarify this as one question, and feel free to ask a another. As Ida mentioned, there are really 2 separate issues here (as the current version stands). There's no harm in asking multiple questions in their own topics, but if they're under the same topic it makes it hard for other users with similar questions to find your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not really giving us all the information we need, ages, is the nieces parent around,  so I will do the best with what little information was given.  do you live with your niece?  When you say our room, does that mean his room?

Your son is being bullied by an older child, you need to talk to her mother and advise her that she needs to teach her child to be nice, to share, no hitting, say please.  Your niece may be an only child and used to getting her way so if mom is not around it is your responsibility to correct her.  If she is two or more she can do a short time out in a room or in a chair.  You may need to look for another place to live if her mother is unwilling to see her child as a bully. Make sure that your son is also playing fair, is he taking all of her toys, does he have toys of his own?  Might be best to just read a book in your room and let your child play sometimes alone especially if your niece is being a bully and her mom is doing nothing about it.

since I don't know your sons age I am going to assume he is about 1 or 2. All children have fears, if he hasn't learned to talk it is very hard for him to tell you what is wrong.  However, you can teach him some sign language along with the word to help him tell you what the issue is until he can learn to speak, there are books out there called baby sign language which are very simple for a baby to learn.

You need to sit down with your family and discuss the issues at hand.  Ask how they want you to handle their child when she is being rude or mean to you or your child.  Advise them how they can do the same with your child.  If they are not willing to help with the issue, you need to either move out or limit the contact between the two children.  That means, if you have to sit in your room with the door closed for hours reading a book to your kid or staring at a wall so he can play then that is what you need to do until you can move out. Best of luck to you and your son.